# Referenced Library not found at runtime

Tags: c#, dll, runtime, revit

I have a VS solution with two projects (using c#), the main project which runs as a dll in Revit, and a class library which the main project references (call it the child dll . . . I'm trying to refactor some code to break it out into an easily reusable library).  When I run the main project I get a file not found exception that is fixed by putting the child dll into the same place that I deploy the main dll in order for revit to find it.

However, this greatly complicates my deployment strategy for a bunch of architects that don't normally contemplate things like dlls (this includes me).  Is there a way to statically link the child dll so that there aren't more files that I have to distribute?

Comment: Putting the DLL somewhere else ought to be the harder problem, nothing much complicated about "put them in the same directory".  Consider the ILMerge utility.

Comment: I guess I tend to agree with your sentiment, except that I don't have a good deployment utility (using the community version) so it's just more to keep track of.  I'll look into the ILMerge utility you mention.

Answer (score 0):

I use a helper class called AssemblyResolver to resolve assemblies in my projects.  It's included in the open source sample Revit application that I've made available on GitHub.
It is initialized in the constructor of the App class (which implements IExternalApplication).
Pass any directories that should be searched for assemblies to the AssemblyResolver constructor.

AssemblyResolver source: https://github.com/StarkBIM/SampleRevitAddin/blob/master/src/StarkBIM.SampleRevitApp.Helpers/AssemblyResolver.cs

App source: https://github.com/StarkBIM/SampleRevitAddin/blob/master/src/StarkBIM.SampleRevitApp.RvtAddin/App.cs

The relevant portion of the App class:

```
string location = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
_assemblyDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(location).ThrowIfNull();

_assemblyResolver = new AssemblyResolver(_assemblyDir);
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += _assemblyResolver.OnAssemblyResolve;
```

Answer (score 0):

[The Building Coder](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com) discussed this setting up the [RvtVa3c Assembly Resolver](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2014/05/rvtva3c-assembly-resolver.html).